# Curl get data from php script without displaying it on that script

Tags: php, curl

I have two php scripts on two different servers. I'm using curl to get data from one to the other (from server 1 to server 2):

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

It works but is there a way to hide the output on server 1 if somebody is accessing that script through its actual url?

Comment: Need to build the Authorization. So, when accessing the api from server 1, we need to provide an authentication.

Comment: Hey @KhoaTruongDinh, i was thinking to set a GET variable with a token in it but would that be oky? I mean i tested it and it works buuuut is there no other fancy way to do it? X_X

Comment: you probably want to do this via `.htaccess` with a deny all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic way to lock down your PHP script is to create a password via a URL parameter. What if you had ?pwd=ABCDEF (create your own password here https://passwordsgenerator.net/) and then your Server-side PHP script can check to see if the password matches the URL parameter, and if it does you can print out the output.
Then modify PHP script #2 to pass your chosen password as a URL Parameter

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer to my question!:D I've done it, it works!